# What foods from Ecuador can I take through US customs for breakfast?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, food-and-drink

I plan to arrive in Florida from Ecuador at 5 am.  I want to pack a breakfast to eat in Florida. (My dietary restrictions are such that I will not be buying food from the vendors at the airport.)

Based on a little web search I think hard cheese and bread might be a safe choice.

My question is, what foods will be allowed through US Customs that I could eat for breakfast?

Comment: You could always just stuff your face just as the plane is landing and not have to worry about what foods are allowed or not

Comment: @PeterM. Yes but it lands at 5 am, which is 4 am my time/

Comment: Well at some point you will need to start buying food in the US, and an early breakfast like that would at least get you out of the airport!

Comment: @PeterM I have a connecting flight - so no time to leave airport. Otherwise it would be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

CBP [tell us](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/us-citizens/know-before-you-go/prohibited-and-restricted-items):

> #### Food Products (Raw and Prepared)
>
> You may bring bakery items and certain cheeses into the United States. The [APHIS Web site](https://www.aphis.usda.gov/aphis/resources/travelers-int) features a Travelers Tips section and Game and Hunting Trophies section that offers extensive information about bringing food and other products into the U.S. Many prepared foods are admissible. However, bush meat made from African wildlife and almost anything containing meat products, such as bouillon, soup mixes, etc., is not admissible. As a general rule, condiments, vinegars, oils, packaged spices, honey, coffee and tea are admissible. Because rice can often harbor insects, it is best to avoid bringing it into the United States. Some imported foods are also subject to requirements of the U.S. Food and Drug Administration.

The APHIS website has a page for [dairy](https://www.aphis.usda.gov/aphis/resources/traveler/intl-travel/milk-dairy-eggs/milk-dairy-eggs) which tells us about restrictions from countries with foot and mouth disease (not Ecuador).

Can’t seem to find a similar page for bread, though.

I do invite you to read those pages and others on both sites, I only had a cursory look at them.

Note that in all cases you must declare all food items you will import. They may ask to inspect them and will tell you if they are OK or need to be binned.

You should also be able to contact CBP before travelling to ask.

Comment: Is there a CBP telephone number or website for such questions?

Comment: Are the baked goods exceptions only for commercially prepared and packaged items or will loose rolls from a bakery be allowed?

Comment: @Yehuda_NYC I don’t know if there is a specific contact for this, but you can find the generic CBP contacts [here](https://www.cbp.gov/about/contact)